# How to set up a proper OpenVPN infrastructure for multiple, independent client-to-client communication with central OpenVPN server in the middle

Tags: networking, security, vpn, openvpn, mobile-devices

I have a little bit of experience with setting up a simple OpenVPN solution where a few clients connect to a central server and communicate altogether in one VPN.

However I am now about to set up an OpenVPN-Infrastructure from scratch and I am questioning my self if my considered approach is a reasonable one. The OpenVPN infrastructure has the following characteristics:

- There are *N* sites of two types:

  - *Mobile sites*
  - *Stationary sites*
- Logically, each *mobile site* has exactly one assigned *stationary site*
- Stationary clients of site *A* may only talk to mobile clients of site *A* and vice versa
- One or multiple mobile clients (linux) *per site* shall connect to a central server (linux) via a mobile network and thus have no fixed IP that can reached directly because of the provider's NAT.
- One or multiple stationary clients (windows) *per site* shall connect to one central server. Each of those clients should have the possibility to connect to one of the mobile clients or a subset of the mobile clients. However, the stationary client must not communicate with more than a single mobile client at a time.
- The communication between two connected clients should be isolated from all other possibly established connections.
- Mobile clients most likely try to always have a connection to the central server. But they might be configured to only connect upon request.
- Stationary clients may establish a connection to the central server at any time and shall be able to communicate instantly to the desired mobile client (when it is also connected, of course)
- A communication amongst all mobile clients of one mobile site or a communication amongst a subset of clients of one mobile site could be a requirement for the future. However even if that requirement would be given, the stationary clients may still only connect to one single mobile client.
- Stationary clients, even belonging to the same site do never have to talk to each other
- One administrative stationary client in charge of the infrastructure must have access to each mobile client (one at a time), no matter which site it belongs to. The administrative client never has to talk to one of the stationary clients.
- The whole infrastructure will (in the first place) have all mobile clients equipped with OpenVPN 2.1.3 which is quite old and might change with firmware updates (nothing that I am in charge of). Stationary clients and server will have far more recent versions of OpenVPN.
- The amount of data that is transferred regularly between stationary and mobile client is quite low (I expect it to be less than a few KiB/s) however this may increase a lot over time, depending which additional communication technologies we will use in the future.

After some reading and thinking I came up with the idea, that all of those requirements can be met by:

- Providing a single central OpenVPN server (Considering using a docker-contained solution like https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn)
- Providing a scripted infrastructure where an adminstrative authority can request a pair of staionary cert/pk and mobile cert/pk as well as performing a configuration change in the OpenVPN server, that sets some routing/ip configs based on the common names that are used.
- Providing a possibility in the stationary clients to select the desired mobile target to connect to by simply connecting to the server using a specific cert/pk pair.

Does this sound like a reasonable mechanism to meet the requirements? If looking at the approach with scalability and speed in mind, should I set up the things like that or should I do some research for alternatives (even other technologies than OpenVPN?)

Thank you for your input in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I have no time pondering your answer completely (though kudos for so well-put explanation, which is rare for SO format, I admit) but here's the list of assorted ideas which you might not yet be familiar with but which might help you going forward:

- You may have multiple OpenVPN instances running on the single server
  (on different ports); this may provide for coarse-grained separation of the groups of clients (and see below for Netfilter).
- Use topology `subnet` to connect your clients and put them into
  different private subnets; you may have any number of private networks wielded by an OpenVPN server instance.
- Enable `client-to-client` option in the server config to allow the clients to communicate with each other within the context of a single OpenVPN server instance.
- Use `push "route <addr> <netmask>"` to tell the clients which *other*
  networks they can reach via their OpenVPN connection
  (that is, networks other than their "native"—the one they happen to be
  connected to when they connect); note that you might need to have the matching `iroute` directives in the OpenVPN config.
- You can use client-specific configuration snippents via the `client-config-dir` parameter (dubbed `ccd`); this allows pushing specific route directives to specific clients so that different clients can connect to different sets of networks, when needed.
- When you have complete OpenVPN setup you might refine it with Netfilter rules (`iptables`) as all the traffic which is handled by OpenVPN still passes via the approptiate tables of the `FORWARD` chain, so here you might control which networks handled by OpenVPN are allowed to talk to each other.
- It's also possible to have OpenVPN accept simultaneous connections of the clients presenting certificates with the same Common Name (CN); this can be used as a last resort to have the same settings applied to different clients (typically via the `ccd` mechanism referred to above). I'd stress this is a last-resort solution as it precludes fine-grained revocation of the access for individual clients.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the kudos and the further input. A friend of mine told me to prefer a ready-to-use solution like a mikrotik routerboard or a mikrotik routeros or even a juniper router over a fully self-configured ovpn solution on a linux server. So, I am now evaluating those things that I am not familar with at all yet.